# Site Not responsive on Epiphany

Tags: html, css, epiphany

I was checking the responsiveness of the site  but this is not supportive on Epiphany browser. Can someone suggest me what changes should i do so that it becomes fully responsive on Epiphany? Thanks in advance

Comment: In which browser?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 Epiphany. It appears three times in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use media queries for the responsive website.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (min-width:200px)
{
     /* Your CSS Code */
}
```